# Ackermann set theory without extensionality?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Scott showed that ZF minus the axiom of regularity is interpreted by ZF minus the axioms of regularity and extensionality.

Is Ackermann set theory interpreted by Akermann set theory without extensionality?